# Improve Xamarin Forms performance with 20 Binding Labels and listview

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, label

I want to make an app with multiple articles and I notice that the app is becoming slower. Is there a better way to write this code so it wil be faster? Thank you for your time and help :)

The xaml page of the article:

```
<ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>

            <StackLayout Padding="5" Spacing="10">
            <Label Text="{Binding Tip1Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black"/>



             <Label Text="{Binding Tip1}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />   



        <Label Text="{Binding Tip1Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" />


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip2}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />

        <Label Text="{Binding Tip2Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" />

        <Label Text="{Binding Tip3}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />

        <Label Text="{Binding Tip3Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" />


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip4}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip4Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" />


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip5}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black"  FontAttributes="Bold" />


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip5Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" />


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip6}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>



        <Label Text="{Binding Tip6Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black"/>


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip7}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="5"/>


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip7Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black"/>


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip8}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="5"/>


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip8Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" />


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip9}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip9Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black"/>


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip10}" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>


        <Label Text="{Binding Tip10Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black"/>
                </StackLayout>




        </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Xaml listview page with al the Titles of the articles:

```
<ScrollView>
 <StackLayout>
    <Image Source="healthmenu.png"/>
    <ListView x:Name="listview" HasUnevenRows="True"
              IsGroupingEnabled="True"
              ItemSelected="listview_ItemSelected_1">
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                     <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20"  Padding="10, 10, 0, 10"/>
                </ViewCell> 
           </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" Padding="10, 10, 0, 10" FontSize="20"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Is there a more optimal way to write this code?
Multiple tips are welcome :)

Comment: Don't use StackLayout, and definitely do not put StackLayouts inside of StackLayouts. Here's more information: https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith%27s-xamarin-forms-performance-tips

Comment: you cannot fix performance problems without analyzing them first.  "is becoming slower" is not a helpful description of the problem.  You need to determine exactly where in your code the issue is occurring before you can fix it.

Comment: How can you determine exactly where in your code the issue is occurring before you can fix it? @Jason

Comment: Also, don't place ListView inside the ScrollView.

Comment: Use a Listview Header for the Image? @MihailDuchev

Comment: Either that, or simply remove the ScrollView. With the current code, the ScrollView has only 1 child view - the StackLayout. If you remove it, nothing will change. You may have to adjust the VerticalOptions, if your ListView doesn't extend till the end, or replace the StackLayout wrapper with a Grid layout.

Comment: @Wazygy For ListView, I suggest you can set `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"`, about improving xamarin.forms app performance, I suggest you can take a look:[Improve Xamarin.Forms App Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance)